# Ionic Sidemenu call to TABS page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to create an ionic's app that will have sidemenu, whereas the sidemenu will consist a set of menus that some of them will call to a TABS page and some will to normal page.

I am able to create the sidemenu as well as its function to call from another normal page to another normal page, however i am stuck with menu that will call to a TABS page. TABS page will be shown but without any content in each tab.

Anyone can help me?

This is some of codes.

**menu.html**

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-royal">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon  button-small" menu-toggle="left"></button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-royal">
      <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/fg-tabs">
          <i class="icon ion-cube"></i>
          Product
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

**app.js**

```
  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'MenuCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.fg-tabs', {
    url: "/fg-tabs",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/fg/fg-tabs.html",
      }
    }
  })
.state('app.fg-in', {
    url: "/fg-in",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/fg/fg-in.html",
        controller: 'FGinListCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

**fg-tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-top">

  <ion-tab title="IN" icon-on="ion-arrow-down-a" icon-off="ion-arrow-up-a" href="#/app/fg-in">
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="OUT" icon-on="ion-arrow-up-a" icon-off="ion-arrow-up-a" href="#/app/fg-out">

    <!-- Tab 2 content -->
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="ENQUIRY" icon-on="ion-document-text" icon-off="ion-document-text" href="#/app/fg-scanner-out">
    <!-- Tab 3 content -->
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: I faced a similar problem some time ago, but the error in my case was because I had put a `<ion-content>` tag inside another. At first sight, the only I can think of is that `fg-tabs.html` content seems not to be in a `ion-view`. Not sure if that matters, tbh. Anyway, check my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579219/ionic-side-menu-and-tabs-with-nested-views-content-of-tab-nested-views-not-show) and the answer it received. Hopefully, it might give you some clue.

Comment: the fg-tabs.html should be inside the `ion-view` wrapper as it has views `menuContent` where the `menuContent` is in this line `<ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>`

Comment: if i put the content code directly inside each `<ion-tab>` then it will show up, but it won't shown if i am using the template.

Comment: What I meant was that `ion-tabs` was, in my case inside an own `ion-view`. Not sure if it applies to your case. Please check the code in my question and the given answer.

Answer (score 0):

use `<ion-item menu-close ui-sref="app.fg-tabs">
          <i class="icon ion-cube"></i>
          Product
        </ion-item>`

insted of `<ion-item menu-close href="#/app/fg-tabs">
          <i class="icon ion-cube"></i>
          Product
        </ion-item>`

for more information please read [this](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref)

Also remove `href` attribute of `ion-tab` and add some content in it. your   `fg-tabs.html` will be

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-top">
<ion-tab title="IN" icon-on="ion-arrow-down-a" icon-off="ion-arrow-up-a">
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent">
        Tab content 1
    </ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
<ion-tab title="OUT" icon-on="ion-arrow-up-a" icon-off="ion-arrow-up-a">
    Tab content 2
</ion-tab>
<ion-tab title="ENQUIRY" icon-on="ion-document-text" icon-off="ion-document-text">
    Tab content 3
</ion-tab>
```

Comment: thanks, learned something new, but it does not answer my question above.

Comment: why i cannot use the template as the content of each tabs?

Comment: yes, you can. see [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/)

Comment: i tried it, but it cannot show the template, see my updated questions